# Android: Master Detail flow, onItemClick() not triggered

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, master-detail

This is my first attempt to a Master-Detail flow application, and i'm a bit lost. I used the Android SDK to create the dummy project and I created a custom ArrayAdapter to replace the plain text list. Now each row has a textfield and a switch. Everything appears normal on the screen, but the problem now is that when i click on a row, nothing happens. I think i'm missing something obvious but i've been looking at it for quite a few hours. I'm guessing i'm doing something wrong with the callbacks. But i don't know what! Here is the code:

ServerListActivity.java:

```
public class ServerListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ServerListFragment.Callbacks {

private boolean mTwoPane;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.server_detail_container) != null) {
        //in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;
        ((ServerListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.server_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }
}

/**
 * Callback method from {@link ServerListFragment.Callbacks} indicating that
 * the item with the given ID was selected.
 */
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    Log.i("info", "item selected");
    if (mTwoPane) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(ServerDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        ServerDetailFragment fragment = new ServerDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.server_detail_container, fragment).commit();

    } else {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ServerDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(ServerDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
```

}

ServerListFragment.java:

```
public class ServerListFragment extends ListFragment {

private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

public interface Callbacks {
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

public ServerListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ServerAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.server_row, android.R.id.text1 ,
            DummyContent.ITEMS));
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("info", "List Fragment Created");
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Log.i("info", "this runs");
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        Log.i("info", "callbacks not found");
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    Log.i("info", "this doesn't run");
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).getIp());
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}
```

}

ServerAdapter.java

```
public class ServerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Server>{

private ArrayList<Server> objects;

public ServerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, int view2, ArrayList<Server> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, view2, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.server_row, null);
    }


    Server i = objects.get(position);

    if (i != null) {

        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.server);

        if (tt != null){
            tt.setText(i.getIp());
        }
    }

    // the view must be returned to our activity
    return v;

}
```

}

Comment: Turns out there is nothing wrong with this code. The problem is when adding a switch on a row item it stops behaving correctly as a list. now that i removed the switch it works normally.. if anyone has any idea how to get past this pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to add a property to the top level element of my xml

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

apparently this stops child elements from overriding the click listeners of the list item.